# Google Apps Script not setting cell value

Tags: google-apps-script

OK, I need a different set of eyes.  The first line below works, setting atest to the contents of cell C1.  The third line does not work as it is not setting any cell value.  It should set row 2, column 2 to "My Spot" but isn't.  I even created the first line by copying the third and adding the -1 and + 1, then changing the setValue to getValue by only changing the "s" character.

```
  var atest = ws_norequests_sheet.getRange(firstEmptyRow - 1, assignedCol + 1).getValue(); 
  var position = 'My Spot';
  ws_norequests_sheet.getRange(firstEmptyRow, assignedCol).setValue(position);
```

**Edit**:

It seems that when I run the containing function via the intended function call (using the client side google.script.run ) this works.  It is in the debugger that it does not work.  I even added code to show the returned range information, cell range A1 notation, sheet name, and file name, and all that comes back as valid. It just doesn't set the cell value when in the debigger mode even though I hard coded the text to put in the cell:

```
  var returntest = ws_norequests_sheet.getRange(firstEmptyRow, assignedCol).setValue(position); 
  ws_norequests_sheet.getRange(firstEmptyRow, nameCol).setValue(name); 
  var returnrange = returntest.getA1Notation();
  var returnsheet = returntest.getSheet().getName();
  var returnss = returntest.getSheet().getParent().getName();
```

Comment: How is this code invoked: manually, by a trigger, from a custom function,...?

Comment: Manually in the debugger.  But I just tested it via the function call (client side google.script.run and it works. (Edited original message to reflect this)  I find that bit odd but I am going with it being OK.

Comment: You haven't provided a [mcve], just a couple of code snippets that are not sufficient to reproduce your problem. Without seeing the function definition, and how you invoke it via `google.script.run`, there's not enough information to provide anything better than guesses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're maybe running into the issue where updates made during a debug run are not instantly displayed in the sheet. They're only displayed when the whole script completes. This is for performance reasons I think, but can make it a pain to debug stuff because the updates lag behind the code.

Comment: This seems to be the problem.  Even though I waited 5 minutes, I was stopping the function at the return; line.  that was the line executed right after all the above code.  When I continued the debug it wrote the data into the appropriate locations.  So not Lag, perhaps, but the write was not completing without running the code further.  Thank you!